How to properly apply bullet spread in a gun in godot 4?
I'm making various guns for a 2D game in godot, and they all extend from a script called arma.gd, everything is working except the bullet spread, it's suppose to make a gap between the bullets, depending on the arc and bullet_qtd, However the gap between the bullets is almost non-existing.
Most weapons are instantiated the player node.
But the bullets are instantiated in the world node by the weapon.
rn the class arma.gd like this:
extends Node2D

class_name Arma

@export var bullet: PackedScene
@export var bullet_qtd: int = 2
@export_range(0, 360) var arc: float = 0
@export_range(0, 20) var fire_rate: float = 1.0
@onready var mundo = $"../../"   #world node
var can_shoot = true


func _ready():
    atirar()


func _physics_process(delta):
    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())


func atirar():
if can_shoot:
    can_shoot = false 
    for i in bullet_qtd:
        var new_bullet = bullet.instantiate()
        new_bullet.position = global_position
            
        if bullet_qtd == 1:
            new_bullet.rotation = global_rotation
                
        else:
            var arc_rad = deg_to_rad(arc)
            var increment = arc_rad / (bullet_qtd - 1)
            new_bullet.global_rotation = (
                (global_rotation - arc_rad / 2) + (increment * i)   
            )
                
        new_bullet.dir = global_rotation
        new_bullet.z_index = z_index
        mundo.add_child(new_bullet)
    await get_tree().create_timer(1 / fire_rate).timeout
    can_shoot = true
    atirar()

I've already tried changing the degrees, the formula to get the new_bullet.rotation, and a few collisions and masks but nothing seems to change the gap.
Bullet class script:
extends CharacterBody2D

class_name Bullet

var zindex:= 1 as int
var dir: float

@export var bullet_velocidade: float
@export var bullet_penetracao:= PlayerVariaveis.penetracao as int
@export var bullet_dano: int
@onready var bullet_vida:= $bullet_vida as Timer


func _ready():
    z_index = zindex
    
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    position += (Vector2.RIGHT*bullet_velocidade).rotated(dir) * delta

The reason I didn't do move_and_colide or move_and_slide is that I begun doing it while the bullet was extending a Area2D not a CharacterBody2D. But if you guys think its better to redo the script I'll do it.
"normal" Bullets:  "theres only this one for now, but they'll always extend from the Bullet class.'
extends Bullet

@onready var dano = bullet_dano * PlayerVariaveis.dano
@onready var velocidade = bullet_velocidade * PlayerVariaveis.velocidade


func _on_bullet_vida_timeout():
    queue_free()


func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):
    if body is Inimigos:
        bullet_penetracao -= 1
        if penetracao <= 0:
            queue_free()
        body._on_hitbox_body_entered(self)


Hi, welcome to SO. Can you show the Bullet code?

@BenderBoy There you go I edit it in the bullet script

new_bullet.dir = global_rotation shouldn’t you use the modified rotation here?

@BenderBoy that's it, thank you much, I really didn't saw it till you point it out

Solution inspired by @BenderBoy:
It did work, just turned out that I didn't pass the modified rotation in the new_bullet.dir:
func atirar():
    if can_shoot:
        can_shoot = false 
        for i in bullet_qtd:
            var new_bullet = bullet.instantiate()
            new_bullet.position = global_position
            
            if bullet_qtd == 1:
                new_bullet.rotation = global_rotation
                new_bullet.dir = global_rotation
                
            else:
                var arc_rad = deg_to_rad(arc)
                var increment = arc_rad / (bullet_qtd - 1)
                var new_rotation = (global_rotation - arc_rad / 2) + (increment * i)    
                new_bullet.global_rotation = new_rotation
                new_bullet.dir = new_rotation
            
            new_bullet.zindex = z_index
            mundo.add_child(new_bullet)
        await get_tree().create_timer(1 / fire_rate).timeout
        can_shoot = true
        atirar()


This answer was posted as an edit to the question How to properly apply bullet spread in a gun in godot 4? [FIXED] by the OP SDG under CC BY-SA 4.0.
